# Dynamic import based on environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-import

In a project I have a environment varible which should be used to specifiy wheter we would like to use HTTPS or not:

```
SSL_ENABLED=1
```

Based on this environment variables I am now trying to use the https or http module:

```
import * as http from parseInt(process.env.SSL_ENABLED || '', 10) ? 'https' : 'http'

const server = http.createServer(...)
```

The import above throws the following typescript error:

```
TS1141: String literal expected.
```

Of course I could work around this, importing both https and http separately, but I wanted to know if there was a way of fixing the above with a single import?

Without typescript the following works just fine:

```
const http = require('http' + parseInt(process.env.SSL_ENABLED || '', 10) ? 's' : ''))
```

Comment: Maybe you can just import both, but then do a conditional assignment to some variable and use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports), which is most convenient when combined with [top-level `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await):

```
const http = await import(parseInt(process.env.SSL_ENABLED || '', 10) ? 'https' : 'http');
// ...
```

Beware that dynamic import can have a negative effect on bundlers (since they can't statically analyze the module graph in order to create the bundles), but this looks like Node.js code you probably aren't bundling.

Or if you can't use top-level `await` for any reason, consume the promise directly:

```
import(parseInt(process.env.SSL_ENABLED || '', 10) ? 'https' : 'http')
.then(http => {
    // ...use `http` here...
});
```

Comment: i think he is trying to use Typescript

Comment: @DevZer0 - I think the TypeScript part of the question is actually because they know how to do this with CommonJS but not with ESM. Otherwise, I don't think TypeScript really matters here (but I haven't looked at the types of `http` vs. `https`, they are probably different; some type shenanigans may also be needed). The question seems focussed on the import rather than typings.

Comment: Nope I am not bundling so that is no issue. Still since the await is on top level I am still having problems with this. Guess I somehow would need to wrap the whole thing in a function.

Comment: @Cyclonecode - Node.js supports top-level `await`, so you shouldnt' need to wrap this in a function. TypeScript only supports it if you have `"module": "esnext"` and `"target": "es20917"` (or higher), that may be the issue. But if you're doing this with TypeScript, getting the types right might be tricky. I'm not sure which way I'd go, a dynamic import or importing both and using a wrapper to handle the HTTP/HTTPS aspect.

Comment: I am currently using `module: esnext` and `target: es6` for this.

Comment: I can solve this without using a dynamic import, but was interested in how you actually could fix this =)

Comment: @Cyclonecode - Node.js is **well** beyond ES6 (2015) these days. Even if you're using an older ESR release, you can still use ES2017+.